# Facebook graph API 2.0 returns Scope ID instead of Canonical ID

Tags: facebook, sdk, scope, connect, canonical-link

I am using facebook connect since 2013 for sign-up and sign-in process. 
I have already implemented it in web and iOS app.

I am using the Canonical ID for identify the users. Means - When the time of sign-up, I have saved the facebook Canonical ID in my database. Then I will compare this saved Canonical ID to Canonical ID return from the facebook for sign-in process.

I have upgraded the SDK with latest version in both web and iOS. I have no problem. I got Canonical ID from both web and iOS.

**But the problem is in Android App**

Now I am creating a new android app for my application. For the facebook connect, I am using the latest android SDK and same facebook app credentials used in the iOS and web. ***But this SDK returns the Scope ID instead of Canonical ID. So I couldn't identify the users, who was already registered in my application using web/iOS facebook sign-up. Lot of users registered in my application using facebook connect and saved Canonical ID  to identify this users.***

Anybody know, how to get the Canonical ID instead of Scope ID using latest Android SDK?

Answer (score 6):

If your Android App is using the latest SDK with version 2.x and is returning the canonical id, rather than the app scoped id, for the same application, then you should file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs.

If the Android App is a separate Application then it will be returning a different App Scoped ID to your other app. You can map your App Scoped IDs across applications by adding them to your Business Manager and using the Business Mapping API. How to do this is documented on Facebook:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business